# OMNET++. Using custom message from imported dynamic library

Tags: omnet++

I have two omnetpp projects: Lab1 and Lab2

From Lab1 .so library is created. Lab 2 is supposed to use this library. It is clear how to import and use modules declared in .ned-files. Problems begin when I try to use message-type from the library (Bitmessage).

bitmessage.msg from the library:

```
message Bitmessage {
    bool bit;
}
```

sSource.h in Lab2:

```
#ifndef SSOURCE_H_
#define SSOURCE_H_

#include <omnetpp.h>
#include "bitmessage_m.h"


class sSource : public cSimpleModule
{
    protected:
        virtual void initialize();
        virtual void handleMessage(cMessage *msg);

    private:
        double p;
};

Define_Module(sSource);

#endif /* SSOURCE_H_ */
```

sSource.cc - source-file in Lab2 which is suppose to use bitmessage:

```
#include <sSource.h>

/*virtual*/ void sSource::initialize()
{
    p = par("p").doubleValue();
}

/*virtual*/ void sSource::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)
{
    if (msg->getArrivalGate() == gate("in"))
    {
        delete msg;

        Bitmessage* bit_msg = new Bitmessage(); // **(!!!)here is error**
        int num_outs = this->gateSize("out");

        for (int i = 0; i < num_outs; ++i)
        {
            send(bit_msg->dup(), "out", i);
        }

        delete bit_msg;
    }

    else
    {
        delete msg;
    }
}
```

The error is following:

```
undefined reference to `Bitmessage::Bitmessage(char const*, int)'
```

How to deal with it? Maybe the problem is that compiler can't interpret .msg-file from the library?

Comment: It sounds like you're not correctly setting the include path, or for some reason your compile process for Lab2 cannot see your `_m.h` file. The only function of the `.msg` files is to save you the trouble of correctly writing the `_m.h` and `_m.cc` files by hand, so that should not be the problem.

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden

Ok. Let's do like it described here [https://omnetpp.org/pmwiki/index.php?n=Main.HowToExtendAProject]

Now IDE automatically creates Makefile with following strings:

**LIBS = -L../Lab1/out/$(CONFIGNAME)  -lLab1
LIBS += -Wl,-rpath,`abspath ../Lab1/out/$(CONFIGNAME)`**

and we must be sure that library and it path are correct. Still I have the same error.

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden

At the same time when we write invalid include header, for example, `#include "bitmessage_m_01.h"`, compiler throws another error: `fatal error: bitmessage_m_01.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: oh, I see. Shouldn't you also include `bitmessage_m.h` in `sSource.cc`? Otherwise I'm out of ideas.